# How to select all rows from one table and any matches from another table if they exist?

Tags: t-sql, select, case

I have a database with 2 tables, Teams and Players:

```
Teams:             

TeamID  | TeamName 
------------------ 
|1      | Team A |
|2      | Team B |
|3      | Team C |
------------------

Players:

PlayerID  | Name      | TeamID | Position
------------------------------------------ 
|1        | Anthony J | 1      | Guard   |
|2        | Sam K     | 2      | Guard   |
|3        | Jack P    | 2      | Forward |
|4        | Carlos B  | 2      | Forward |
------------------------------------------
```

I am looking to select a column for the names of all teams in the database, regardless of whether they have players or not. The next column should display their name if their position is 'Forward', or null if not. There should be a row for each 'Forward' player that is on the team.

The query I am using to get this data is:

```
SELECT T.TeamName,

CASE WHEN P.Position = 'Forward'
    THEN P.Name
END as ForwardPlayer

FROM Teams T
LEFT JOIN Players P on T.TeamID = P.TeamID
```

All of the data I require resides in this data set, except there is a row with NULL for a team that DOES have a Forward, i.e:

```
TeamName  | ForwardPlayer
-------------------------
|Team A   | NULL        |
|Team B   | Jack B      |
|Team B   | Carlos B    |
|Team B   | NULL        |
|Team C   | NULL        |
```

I realise this 4th row exists because there is a player for the team that doesn't meet the case condition, so the result is NULL.

Putting a where clause on the outer query to restrict the data set to 'Forward' players will omit all the teams without any forward players. I need all of the teams names to be present in the data set.

Using a nested select to obtain this will only work if there is 1 Foward for each team.

Is there any way to omit these NULL rows for teams that do have a player that meets this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do `CASE`. You just straight up want to restrict the players to only forward ones, then do the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T.TeamName, P.Name
FROM Teams T
LEFT JOIN Players P ON T.TeamID = P.TeamID
  AND P.Position = 'Forward'
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew it couldn't be particular complex to get this to work. Much appreciated, exactly what I needed.